# Map errors to observable using C# ReactiveX

Tags: c#, exception, observable, reactivex

I have an observable `MyObservable<Object>` which can throw `CustomExceptions` where

```
private class CustomException : Exception
```

What I want to do is convert the `CustomExceptions` into objects and emit those in a new observable.

This is my solution so far but I was wondering if this could be done without having to directly call the Subject's onNext, onCompleted or onError methods.

```
var MySubject = new Subject<NewObject>();

MyObservable.Catch<Object, CustomException>(
            ex =>
            {
                NewObject o = new NewObject(ex.Message);
                MySubject.OnNext(o);
                return Observable.Empty<Object>();
            });

IObservable<IList<NewObject>> listObservable = MySubject.ToList();
```

Edit: Thanks ibebbs! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch and map exceptions without a subject by using the [Materialize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229453.aspx) function as shown here:

```
var errorObservable = source
    .Select(projection)
    .Materialize()
    .Where(notification => notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
    .Select(notification => notification.Exception)
    .OfType<CustomException>()
    .Select(exception => new NewObject(exception.Message));
```

The `Materialize` function takes an `IObservable<T>` and maps it to a `IObservable<Notification<T>>` where each Notification has a `Kind` of `OnNext`, `OnError` or `OnComplete`. The above observable simply looks for Notifications with a ``` Kind`` of OnError and with the Exception being an instance of CustomException then projects these exceptions into an ```IObservable```.

Here is a unit test showing this working:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldEmitErrorsToObservable()
{
    Subject<int> source = new Subject<int>();
    List<int> values = new List<int>();
    List<NewObject> errors = new List<NewObject>();

    Func<int, int> projection =
        value =>
        {
            if (value % 2 == 1) throw new CustomException("Item is odd");

            return value;
        };

    Func<CustomException, IObservable<int>> catcher = null;

    catcher = ex => source.Select(projection).Catch(catcher);

    var errorObservable = source
        .Select(projection)
        .Materialize()
        .Where(notification => notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
        .Select(notification => notification.Exception)
        .OfType<CustomException>()
        .Select(exception => new NewObject(exception.Message));

    var normalSubscription = source.Select(projection).Catch(catcher).Subscribe(values.Add);
    var errorSubscription = errorObservable.Subscribe(errors.Add);

    source.OnNext(0);
    source.OnNext(1);
    source.OnNext(2);

    Assert.Equal(2, values.Count);
    Assert.Equal(1, errors.Count);
}
```

However, as you can see with the construed catch mechanisms employed above, exception handling in Rx can be tricky to get right and even more difficult to do elegantly. Instead, consider that [Exceptions should be Exceptional](http://mattwarren.org/2016/12/20/Why-Exceptions-should-be-Exceptional/) and, if you expect an class of error such that you've written a custom exception for it, then the error is not really exceptional but part of a process flow that must handle these errors.

In this instance, I would recommend projecting the observable into a class which embodies the "try this operation and record the result, be it a value or an exception" and using this further along the execution chain.

In the example below, I use a "Fallible" class to capture the result or exception of an operation and then subscribe to a stream of "Fallible" instances, separating the errors from values. As you will see, the code is both neater and better performing as both the errors and values share a single subscription to the underlying source:

```
internal class Fallible
{
    public static Fallible<TResult> Try<TResult, TException>(Func<TResult> action) where TException : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            return Success(action());
        }
        catch (TException exception)
        {
            return Error<TResult>(exception);
        }
    }

    public static Fallible<T> Success<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Fallible<T>(value);
    }

    public static Fallible<T> Error<T>(Exception exception)
    {
        return new Fallible<T>(exception);
    }
}

internal class Fallible<T>
{
    public Fallible(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        IsSuccess = true;
    }

    public Fallible(Exception exception)
    {
        Exception = exception;
        IsError = true;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public bool IsError { get; private set; }
}

[Fact]
public void ShouldMapErrorsToFallible()
{
    Subject<int> source = new Subject<int>();
    List<int> values = new List<int>();
    List<NewObject> errors = new List<NewObject>();

    Func<int, int> projection =
        value =>
        {
            if (value % 2 == 1) throw new CustomException("Item is odd");

            return value;
        };

    var observable = source
        .Select(value => Fallible.Try<int, CustomException>(() => projection(value)))
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

    var errorSubscription = observable
        .Where(fallible => fallible.IsError)
        .Select(fallible => new NewObject(fallible.Exception.Message))
        .Subscribe(errors.Add);

    var normalSubscription = observable
        .Where(fallible => fallible.IsSuccess)
        .Select(fallible => fallible.Value)
        .Subscribe(values.Add);

    source.OnNext(0);
    source.OnNext(1);
    source.OnNext(2);

    Assert.Equal(2, values.Count);
    Assert.Equal(1, errors.Count);
}
```

Hope it helps.